# Laravel 5.2 User/Following System: hasMany Relation

Tags: has-many, laravel-5

I'm stuck on a problem: I've created a simple user following system so users can follow each other. I'm using a table named `follows` to store the relation. I've created a `hasMany` relationship in my `User` class, and, when retrieving the results I'm getting exactly what I expect, however, I'd like to get some additional information from the users table, such as the username, avatar, etc. How do I go about this?

The `follows` table

```
// following_id is the person being followed

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('follows', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('following_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['user_id', 'following_id']);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

The `User` class

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // a user can have many followers
    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Follow::class, 'following_id');
    }


    // a user may be following many people
    public function following()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Follow::class);
    }
}
```

The method I'm calling in `UsersController` to see the results

```
// route is /{username}/followers

public function followers($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    // get the user's followers
    $followers = $user->following;

    return $followers;
}
```

The current results are

```
[
    {
        id: 24,
        user_id: 3,
        following_id: 1,
        created_at: "2016-02-13 11:42:59",
        updated_at: "2016-02-13 11:43:02"
    }
]
```

However, I'd like them to be the following: where `fredflintstone` is the user with ID of 1; e.g.; the user who is following user 3

```
[
    {
        id: 24,
        user_id: 3,
        following_id: 1,
        following_username: 'fredflintstone',
        created_at: "2016-02-13 11:42:59",
        updated_at: "2016-02-13 11:43:02"
    }
]
```

I've also created a `Follow` model, which is currently empty. I tried adding an inverse `belongsTo` relationship in it, but it didn't work. Mayhaps I did it wrong?

Comment: do this User::where('username', $username)->with('following')->first();

Comment: @AmirBar Couldn't get that to work.

Comment: why? you need to give more info, when you do dd(User::where('username', $username)->with('following')->first()) what happen?

Comment: I went back and did a fresh laravel install so I could try this all by itself. When I did what you suggested I got the relations in a collection, but no additional information about the user being followed, just the `following_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using laravel for a long time,and i suggest you use join instead if laravel built in model for 'with'

Here is the code of using join, modify it according to your use

```
    public function followers($username)
        {
            $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
//Follower your model name for the follows table
//if you dont have a model use DB::table('follows') instead
            $followers=Follower::where('user_id',$user->id)
              ->join('users as follower','follower.id','=','follows.following_id')
              ->select('follows.id','follows.following_id','follows. user_id','follower.name as following_username')->get();


            return $followers;
        }
```

Comment: This solution does give me some control over what is returned... is it not possible the using a relation?

Comment: you can use something like this
User::where('username', $username)->with('following')->first();

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to join the users table to the query.

```
public function following()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Follow::class, 'user_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'follows.following_id')
        ->select('user_id','username');
}
```